# Continuously differentiable functions are weakly differentiable

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations, sobolev-spaces, weak-derivatives

Let $\Omega\subseteq\mathbb R^n$ be a bounded domain and $u\in C^1(\Omega)$. I want to show, that $u$ is *weakly differentiable*, i.e. $$\int_\Omega\psi\frac{\partial u}{\partial x_i}d\lambda^n=-\int_\Omega u\frac{\partial \psi}{\partial x_i}d\lambda^n\;\;\;\text{for all }\psi\in C_c^1(\Omega)\;.$$ It doesn't seem to be elementary provable. Do we need to approximate $u$ or $\partial_iu$ in some way?

Comment: Integrate by parts ... evaluation terms vanish.

Comment: Once you fix the typo this is just integration by parts! (This being just integration by parts is sort of the reason the definition of weak differentiability is what it is...)

Answer (score 0):

The proof that you are looking for can be found in the page 258 of the [Evans book](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&lpg=PA375&dq=%22Motivation%20for%20definition%20of%20weak%22&hl=pt-BR&pg=PA258#v=onepage&q=%22Motivation%20for%20definition%20of%20weak%22&f=false):

[image]